# LiveData observing in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

As of 2019, I'm trying to follow a best practice on where to start observing `LiveData` in Fragments and if I should pass `this` or `viewLifecycleOwner` as a parameter to the `observe()` method.

- According to this [Google official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata), I should observe in `onActivityCreated()` passing `this` (the fragment) as parameter.
- According to this [Google sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/ui/user/UserFragment.kt), I should observe in `onViewCreated()` passing `viewLifecycleOwner` as parameter.
- According to this [I/O video](https://youtu.be/pErTyQpA390?t=459), I shouldn't use `this` but instead `viewLifecycleOwner`, but doesn't specify where should I start observing.
- According to this pitfalls [post](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/architecture-components-pitfalls-part-1-9300dd969808), I should observe in `onActivityCreated()` and use `viewLifecycleOwner`.

So, where should I start observing? And should I either use `this` or `viewLifecycleOwner`?

Comment: I feel your pain. Android is moving really fast with Jetpack and best practices are all over the place.

Comment: Adding a new source where it states it should be done in `onCreateView()` using `viewLifecycleOwner` https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-live-data/#4

Answer (score 25):

If observing from an Activity you can observe on `onCreate()` and use `this` for the LifecycleOwner as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#oncreate):

> If you have a lifecycle-aware component that is hooked up to the lifecycle of your activity it will receive the ON_CREATE event. The method annotated with @OnLifecycleEvent will be called so your lifecycle-aware component can perform any setup code it needs for the created state.

Now if you are observing within a Fragment you can observe on `onViewCreated()` or `onActivityCreated()` and you should use `getViewLifecycleOwner()` and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#getViewLifecycleOwner()) is why:

> Get a LifecycleOwner that represents the Fragment's View lifecycle. In most cases, this mirrors the lifecycle of the Fragment itself, but in cases of detached Fragments, the lifecycle of the Fragment can be considerably longer than the lifecycle of the View itself.

Comment: ```onActivityCreated``` is deprecated only option is ```onViewCreated```

Comment: DO NOT PASS `viewLifecycleOwner` for `DialogFragment`. 
When subscribing to lifecycle-aware components such as `LiveData`, you should never use `viewLifecycleOwner` as the `LifecycleOwner` in a `DialogFragment` that uses `Dialogs`. Instead, use the `DialogFragment` itself, or if you're using Jetpack Navigation, use the `NavBackStackEntry`.
ref:https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/dialogs

Answer (score 2):

As in the I/O talk Yigit says, the Fragment and its view has different lifecycles. You would need to identify if your `LiveData` is related to the fragment or its view and pass the one desired. The compiler will accept both since both are implementations of `LifecycleOwner`

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't matter whether you do it on `onViewCreated` or `onActivityCreated`. Both are called when the fragment is inflated, `onViewCreated` first, `onActivityCreated` afterwards. It's really a matter of preference.

The `LiveData` object takes a `LifecycleOwner`, and both `Fragment` and `Activity` implement the interface, so you just need to pass `this`.

Comment: So, `viewLifeCycleOwner` is not a part of the equation?

Comment: `viewLifeCycleOwner` refers to the lifecycle of the root view in the fragment. For most intents and purposes, that lifecycle is the same as the fragment, but in some edge cases they might be different. Unless you have a specific need to track that lifecycle, I'd suggest to stick to `this`.

Comment: ```onActivityCreated``` is deprecated only option is ```onViewCreated```